# UINavigationController: push self?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a custom class which is a UITableViewController, this is inside of a UINavigationController.  Normally, when I click a cell, I push a new class onto the stack and it is fine.  This time, I would like to push self onto the stack (passing a different string onLoad so that I load different content), so that I can reuse my code, is this possible? Or do I always have to create a secondary class to push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than "pushing yourself", you can push a new instance of the same view controller yes. Simply create a new one like so:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MyView"];
viewController.customString = @"Something else";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];
```

I haven't tested this, and it's late so there might be bits wrong but you should be ok with that. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Well that was easy enough! Thanks!

Comment: No problemo. Glad I could help. I've just got off minecraft and seen it's gone 1am!! Bed time for me...

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MyView"];
viewController.customString = @"Something else";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];
```

Comment: Note, that's not creating `a secondary class`, but creating the new instance of the same type.